# How do you make a non-unique/repeating id for a database column?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

How do you make a non-unique id for a database?
I have three databases, User, Document, and Chapter; each user has multiple documents and each document has multiple users. When I try to print the chapter id when there is only one chapter in that document, the id is the number of ALL chapter in the chapter database, not just the ones related to the parent doc.

**there can be 2 chapters with the same id, but if they have the same id they can't have the same document id.**

How can I make the id# start over from 1 when I enter a different document?

**My Database**

```
class Chapter(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    document_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('document.id'))

class Document(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    chapters = db.relationship('Chapter',backref='parentDoc')
```

**My HTML**

```
{% for chapter in document.chapters %}
  <a href="/{{document.id}}/{{chapter.id}}" class="centerChapter">
    <button>
      <h5 class="chapterNumber">{{chapter.id}}</h5>
    </button>
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to remove primary_key, but that gave me an error.